# Understanding AWS ELB, multiple ELB per subnet or one ELB per subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, subnet, amazon-elb

So I'm trying to setup a production site and I'm new to the devops world. I have a setup that consists of four components:

```
1) Node.js API Server
2) Memcached Elasticache cluster
3) Postgresql RDS
4) Rabbitmq Cluster 3 nodes-> Handcrafted by me
```

With clustering my rabbitmq configurations and load balancing multiple node api servers, how do I want to configure the load balancers?

If both rabbitmq and node api servers need to be accessible by the internet, do I need to separate the node api servers from the rabbitmq clusters into their own subnets and put an external AWS loadbalancer per subnet with their own internet gateways? Or can I put but rabbitmq clusters and node.js api servers in the same subnet and have 2 external facing load balancers for that one subnet?

Comment: It's up to you. Both ways work.

Comment: Ok cool thanks, then I don't have to worry.